# Regex: Search for verb roots

Tags: regex

I've seen the results for classifying verbs by their endings. But I want to use Regular Expressions to find verb roots for regular verbs in Spanish.

I'm using this fancy site: http://regexpal.com/ 
Which I suspect may not be compatible with my end use, but will be a great starting point.

From what I have seen, the caret should identify all strings after it based on your supplied string-pattern.

So, to me:

```
ˆgust
```

Should find "gusta", "gustan", "gustamos", "gustas","gustar".

I know that I'm way off, but looking at many of the pages and tutorials and examples, I don't see anything that looks similar to what I want to do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you look for regex matching you'll get only the matching part, meaning, in case you have the word "gustan" and you're trying to match it with `^gust` like you suggested, the output of the matcher will be "gust" - which is not what you want (you want the whole word).

So instead of matching to `^gust` try matching to `^gust\w*$` which means anything that starts with "gust" and has zero or more characters following it.

Comment: I would be careful using `.*` because that will match any character, including punctuations, hyphens etc.... although it may be appropriate for this application due to the fact you might be crossing paths with some special characters (accented "e", "n" with the tilda and so on..)

Comment: @A.O. you're right - I modified my answer to end the matching with anything that is not a space, but it could be extended to include other cases as well - it depends on the possible inputs

Comment: You guys are great. I found a big part of my problem in the process - My keyboard inadvertently produces the incorrect caret. I need ^ and I get ˆ usually. This is a problem with the way the international keyboard gets mapped into UTF-8 sometimes, I believe.

Comment: Sure thing! I decided to modify my answer to include `\w` at the end since your input is not likely to contain digits or `_` and it includes all the possible a-z characters (case insensitive)

Comment: `\w A word character (same as [_a-zA-Z0-9])` it still will contain digits.

Comment: @alfasin why don't you just use `[a-zA-Z]` to make sure it's a character?

Comment: @progenhard cause `\w` is shorter and would *probably* be sufficient to the kind of input he uses. But you can definitely use `[a-zA-Z]` as well :)

Answer (score 2):

```
^(gust[a-zA-Z]*)$
```

[image: Regular expression visualization]

[Edit live on Debuggex](http://www.debuggex.com/r/T06rEtFFGdARBnEa)

- `^` denotes the start of the line
- `[a-zA-Z]` letters only
- `*` means zero or more
- `()` is called a capture group
- `$` is the end of the line

If you want to edit with different words you could do this...

```
^((?:gust|otherwords)[a-zA-Z]*)$
```

[image: Regular expression visualization]

[Edit live on Debuggex](http://www.debuggex.com/r/C03phpfPqGegls6X)

all you have to change/edit is `|otherwords` this will allow you to add more words that you want to match.

please read more about [regex here](http://www.regular-expressions.info/) and use [debugexx.com](http://www.debuggex.com/) to experiment.

Comment: I liked very much your diagram... I'm new to regex and this helped a lot to understand what each operator is doing in the expression!