# Possible combination (variations) of words in a string variable in stata

Tags: stata

I have a string variable containing school names and I need to find all the possible combination of each word in this string variable in stata:

For example variation of a word "Academy" would be:

Academy,
Academy, 
acdamey, 
aacdemy, 
dmcaamy,
aacedmy, 
and so on.

I need this to standardize the raw data of school names, which has many typos of each word due to data entry issues, like the ones given above for "academy".

Comment: What is the relevance to Excel ?

Comment: Its possible someone with expertise in Excel can suggest a solution to it!

Comment: Not entirely sure I fully understand your problem, but you might want to take a look at the user-written command `strgroup`.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. I will look into it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending whether your data is already in the Excel sheets or a file, you can either use regex trying to match all possible combinations (and probably fix them when found) or parse the strings first before bringing them into Excel. In either case you could make a file (or Excel list/table/area/etc.) that includes all the common typos and pick each typo as regex match to use when comparing to your actual input.

Making regexp that would actually find all possible cases is next to impossible, especially if there are cases where very similar (but correct) names for schools exist. In any case direct regexps would be very messy and complex, so I would advice you to parse the data by finding first the correct form, excluding it and then using (greedy) search/regex to find the typoed versions. You can then save the typos to use them as a filter/match/pattern.

To get some sort of starting ideas, check this links:

[Regex: Search for verb roots](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18792136/regex-search-for-verb-roots)

[Read text file and extract string into Excel sheet using regex](http://www.ozgrid.com/forum/showthread.php?t=167410)

*P.s You should keep the count of all strings/school names and finally get a list of all names that did not match correct form or any of your regexp filters, so you can manually insert/correct them.*

Comment: Thank you! This seems an intelligent way to tackle the issue.